# Contains a part of string or end of line

Tags: php, regex

I want to detect, if URL has language code. It can be either `en` or `sk`, but there will be more in the future.

These are URLs I want to try:

```
1 - http://localhost/website/en
2 - http://localhost/website/endorphin
3 - http://localhost/website/en/
4 - http://localhost/website/en/test
5 - http://localhost/website/sk/entity
```

So, for example, I want to know if URL has `en` language code. I try URLs wrote above and results are:

```
1 - false - should be TRUE
2 - false - OK
3 - true - OK
4 - true - OK
5 - false - OK
```

And pattern I tried: `/(\/en[\/{0,1}|\b])/mi`.

Live preview: [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56cec6df866e862347e5314cd2552b2c34db3e98)

Comment: for [en or sk](https://regex101.com/r/qM8bT9/1)

Comment: Thanks, you should send it as answer.

Comment: @rock321987 I'm not realy good at regex, I wanted to select one `/` or none. I know, lame.

Comment: your thinking was correct though

Comment: correct one of your :- `\/\ben\b\/{0,1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will work for `en` or `sk`

```
\/(en|sk)(?:\/|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM8bT9/4)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\/ #Match a / literally
 ( #Capturing group
  en #Match en literally
  | #Alternation(OR)
  sk #Match sk literally
 )
 (?: #Non-capturing group
  \/ #Match a / literally
    | Alternation(OR)
  $ #End of string
 )
```

Comment: `/` and `$` are word boundaries, so both of your `\b`s are unnecessary.